# Average of three biggest parameters out of five without using sorting algorithm or vector/array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, average

I'm trying to create a function with has 5 input parameters and returns the average of the 3 biggest. However I'm not supposed to use a sorting algorithm, vector/arrays or function libraries and still try to use to develop the most efficient logic possible.

So far I've come up with the code below. Is it the most efficient possible considering the restrictions?

```
float avg3of5(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e) {                                          
    float min;
    float min2;

    min = a;
    if (b < min) {
        min2 = min;
        min = b;
    }
    else {
    min2 = b;
    }

    if (c < min) {
        min2 = min;
        min = c;
    }
    else {
        if (c < min2) {
            min2 = c;
        }
    }

    if (d < min) {
        min2 = min;
        min = d;
    }
    else {
        if (d < min2) {
            min2 = d;
        }
    }

    if (e < min) {
        min2 = min;
        min = e;
    }
    else {
        if (e < min2) {
            min2 = e;
        }
    }

    Return = (a + b + c + d + e - min - min2) / 3
}
```

Comment: If they code is working and you want suggestions on improvements then the question should be moved over to [codereview.se]. And please pick a single language - C and C++ are different languages with possibly different answers.

Comment: There are lots of ways to measure efficiency, making this a rather broad question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One thing that immediately jumps out at me is the repetition caused by:

```
if (b < min) {
    min2 = min;
    min = b;
}
else {
    min2 = b;
}
```

It may be better to extract this logic into a function and then call it instead:

```
#include <iostream>

float avg3of5(const float, const float, const float, const float, const float);
void adjustmins(const float, float*, float*);

int main()
{
    std::cout << avg3of5(4,6,2,6,3);
}

float avg3of5(const float a, const float b, const float c, const float d, const float e){                                          
    float min;
    float min2;

    min = a;

    adjustmins(b, &min, &min2);
    adjustmins(c, &min, &min2);
    adjustmins(d, &min, &min2);
    adjustmins(e, &min, &min2);

    return (a + b + c + d + e - min - min2) / 3;
}

void adjustmins(const float n, float* min, float* min2){
    if (n < *min) {
        *min2 = *min;
        *min = n;
    }
    else {
        *min2 = n;
    }
}
```

I can't tell you if this is more efficient in terms of processing time, but there's much less repetition.

If you'd prefer to use references rather than pointers use this (C++ only):

```
void adjustmins(const float, float&, float&);
```

and

```
void adjustmins(const float n, float& min, float& min2){
    if (n < min) {
        min2 = min;
        min = n;
    }
    else {
        min2 = n;
    }
}
```

then call with:

```
adjustmins(b, min, min2);
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems more concise